# EF CORE understanding relationships in a Gym setting

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Ok I am kinda stuck I need a ef query that will get me the following data.

I have sessions which are created at the Gym I am using ef core here so

In the main grid I need to list the students that our their for the workout that day.

| ID | Session Name | Start Date | TeamId |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test 1 | 06/11/2021 | 1 | --- |
| 2 | Test 2 | 05/11/2021 | 2 | --- |

I have table Students which has a team Id

| ID | FirstName | Last Name | TeamId |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Matt | Smith | 1 | --- |
| 2 | Martha | Jones | 2 | --- |

Team Includes the students and is linked back to the Student via Team Id

| ID | Name | Session Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test Team | 1 |
| !2 | Test Team 2 | 2 |

For Example what I want to be able to do is Pick the session that is on the start date of the 5 and display only the students attending that day.

My Poco Class for Session

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int OccuranceType { get; set; }
    public int? StaffId { get; set; }
    public int? Day { get; set; }
    public int? Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team? Team { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Student

```
public class Student
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Type { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Gender { get; set; }
    public string? Photo { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string? AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string? AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string? State { get; set; }
    public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConditioningWorkout> ConditioningWorkouts { get; set; }
    public ConditioningWorkout? ConditioningWorkout { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BikeWorkOut> BikeWorkOuts { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Notes>? Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal? TB { get; set; }
    public decimal? OP { get; set; }
    public decimal? PU { get; set; }
    public decimal? PB { get; set; }
    public decimal? BP { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Team

```
public  class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid? TennantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CoachId { get; set; }
    public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students {  get; set;}
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int? SessionId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I think I need to have some link back from the Student to the session but because they can block book sessions and team level I dont no how to achieve this.

Comment: Why link session to teams and teams to sessions? Surely one of these can disappear?

Comment: The can either block book a team or a student @CaiusJard So A team could have ten students or else they could book a single student

Comment: So, how do you record a session having only one student? Do you put them ina  team of one?

Comment: Correct maybe not the best way to do it though @CaiusJard

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Session has a Team(s?) and a Team has a Student(s), so it's reasonably straight forward:

```
context.Sessions.Include(s => s.Team).ThenInclude(t => t.Students)
  .Where(s => s.StartDate == new DateTime(2021, 11, 5))
```

This gets you a collections of sessions that should have their Team property populated with a Team, and in turn that Team has a Students collection that is populated with Students

Comment: Thanks ill give this  a shot thank u